# Totalise row in pivot table - Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot

I have a spreadsheet I used to calculate time spend on projects. I take the weekly timesheets sent to me and I pick out and log the hours spent on a task for a specific person on a specific project.

I then want to totalise the time spent on each task, by each person, then the total time spent on the project by each person. Finally, a total time spent on the project my everyone.

I have created a pivot table to handle most of this, however I can not get the pivot table to totalise rows and columns. (Columns totalise fine) I could just manually SUM the rows, however I have to recreate / move the SUM each time I add a new task.

I hope the demo, downloadable from the link below shows what I want to achieve. Surely there has to be a way and I just can't see the wood for the trees.

Thanks

www.xserv.co.uk/MASTER Project Time_DEMO.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2010: In the pivot-table-options (e.g. from pivot table context menu / right click) select the first two check boxes in the sums and filters tab. This gives you sums (or whatever you select in the other options) of each row and column.

Comment: humm... those options are already ticked, but I'm only totaling colums

Comment: Oh, I did not understand it. You want a common total of the different fields. You can get those by adding a computed field with the formula MyTotal='CTS Install Ham' +'CTS Install Lec' +'CTS Edin'
(found in the "options" ribbon under 'Fields, Elements and Groups')

Comment: do you need the your file back with the modifications? Or can you find the custom fields?